# Finding the Average (confused)

Tags: c++, math, average, probability, mean

Trying to find average of Olympic medal winners under the age of 20 for a particular year. Here is data:

- 400 total events
- 300 individuals; 85 persons 20yrs and younger, 215 persons 21yrs and Older.
- Total medals earned 20 years old and younger = 122 medals.

I am trying to find the average of medals received by persons 20 years old and younger.

I am using C++ language.

Comment: What programming language are you using? If your question is not about programming, it is off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hm, 85 persons earned 122 medals. This means that the average number of medals per person is 1.4353.

Comment: The only real difficulty here is the ambiguity of the phrase *"average of Olympic medal winners under the age of 20"*; Once you've rephrased it into something clear and unambiguous, calculating the result should be easy.

Comment: @VLL c++ language